# Kohana: Validation on a multidimensional array

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

How to perform a validation of a multidimensional array?

Array (print_r):

```
Array ( 
    [btitel] => Array ( [1] => [2] => ) 
    [btext]  => Array ( [1] => [2] => ) 
)
```

The deepest values may not be empty and must have more then 3 characters.

Is it possible to perform this in just one instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom validation rule...

OR

create validation for each item in array...

```
$btitel_validation = Validation::factory($array['btitel'])...
$btext = Validation::factory($array['btext'])...
```

Comment: And do you have an example?